# Delegate and protocols in ios 6 seem does not work

Tags: ios6

I have created a simple TableView application using delegate and protocols, it worked in ios 5 but when i updated my xcode, i does not work in ios 6.
The code is like this:

In child view:

```
@class AddItemViewController;
@class CheckListItem;
@protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addItemViewControllerDidCancel: (AddItemViewController *)controller;
- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFnishAddingItem:(CheckListItem *)item;

@end


@interface AddItemViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

//declare an property
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AddItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

in childview.m:
- (void)addItemViewControllerDidCancel: (AddItemViewController *)controller{
//i do something here
}

in parentview.h:
#import "AddItemViewController.h"

@interface CheckListViewController : UITableViewController <AddItemViewControllerDelegate>

-(IBAction)addItem;

@end

in parentview.m:
- (void)addItemViewControllerDidCancel:(AddItemViewController *)controller
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        AddItemViewController *controller = (AddItemViewController *)navigationController;
        controller.delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"perform prepare for segue");

    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your child view you have to call [delegate addItemViewControllerDidCancel: (AddItemViewController *)controller], instead of just calling the method.

If you change that, it should work :)